# python tuple ending with comma difference

Tags: python, mysql-python

What is the difference between

```
("a")
```

and

```
("a",)
```

I noticed that for example mysql wrapper parameters formatting doesn't work with the first case, it must end with comma.

```
cursorA.execute(query, (url,))
```

Comment: `("a")` is not a tuple at all, it is just `"a"`. The parentheses have no semantic meaning other than determining scope and precedence. The comma makes the tuple.

Comment: @user2390182: Aside from the special case of the empty `tuple`, which is `()`, requiring the parentheses and prohibiting commas. But yes, in all other cases, the parentheses are only needed for disambiguation/grouping, they're not what defines a `tuple`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you write only one element in parentheses (), the parentheses () are ignored and not considered a tuple.

```
x = ("a")

print(type(x))
```

output: `str`

to generate a one-element tuple, a comma `,` is needed at the end.

```
x = ("a", )

print(type(x))
```

ouput : `tuple`

Answer (score 1):

The First will create a string and the second will make a tuple. That's actually the difference between making a tuple and a string between two parentheses.

Answer (score 1):

when using only parentheses, you are not creating a tuple, because the interpreter treats this as increasing operator precedence (just like parentheses in mathematics), and if you put a comma, the interpreter will understand that we are trying to create a tuple with one element, and do not increase priority

Answer (score 0):

This code below which is not **"Tuple"** is :

```py
x = ("a") # Is not Tuple
```

Same as this code below:

```py
x = "a"
```

While this code below is **"Tuple"**:

```py
("a",) # Is Tuple
```